# Proving a Set is a Club Set

Tags: set-theory

The question goes like this,

Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable regular cardinal and let $f:\kappa^{<\omega}\rightarrow\kappa$.

Prove that the set

$$ C = \left\{\alpha \ \big|\ \text{range}(f\restriction\alpha^{<\omega})\subseteq\alpha\wedge\alpha<\kappa  \right\} $$

is a club.

I managed to prove that it is closed. I'm having trouble proving the unbounded part.

The direction I took was to assume $\sup C=\gamma < \kappa $ and build a maximal function from $\omega\rightarrow\kappa$ using an infinite branch of $\kappa^{<\omega}$ to contradict the regularity of $\kappa$. But I don't think it is the right direction.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always easy to prove this sort of statement in the positive.

Take $\alpha$, now define $\beta_0=\alpha+1$, and let $\beta_{n+1}=\sup\operatorname{range}(f\restriction\beta_n^{<\omega})$. Finally, let $\beta=\sup\beta_n$. Then $\operatorname{range}(f\restriction\beta^{<\omega})\subseteq\beta$: if $\vec x\in\beta^{<\omega}$, then there is some $n<\omega$ such that $\vec x\in\beta_n^{<\omega}$, so $f(\vec x)<\beta_{n+1}$.

And since $\alpha<\beta_0\leq\beta_1\leq\dots\beta$, we are done.